# Why are all coding conventions central?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, stylecop, roslyn-code-analysis

Coding conventions are often a topic that cause a lot of debatting in teams. When a a team agrees on conventions tools like stylecop are used to help to enforce those rules.

Why is this centralized rule system necessary? Isn't it possible to adjust the visual appearance of source code on the fly with the help of an ide (e.g Visual Studio) or with a git extension?

Basically the repository contains

```
 private string ____foo;
```

and after checking out people see either

```
private string foo;
```

or

```
private string _foo;
```

or

```
private strng m_foo;
```

depending on their personal settings.

Same goes for check-ins , write in your personal style and stored on repository in agnostic form.

Answer (score 4):

Cause it requires other conventions:

- All team members must use an editor that supports this
- Or run a git extension that takes additional time and needs cross platform support
- You'd still need to store a central representation of your code for the "master repo style"
- Pair Programming and Mob Programming and LiveShare would be much harder with all the preferences mixed

And may cause issues:

- Doesn't scale well in large repos
- Increases checkout times
- Could change the names of Public interface elements
- Can cause reflection issues
- Can cause all kinds of parser bugs & small differences
- Could cause all kinds of funny (local) merge and working folder issues

Just look at all the mess core.autocrlf creates, please not more of this madness.

Tools like EditorConfig, Roslyn, Resharper make it so easy to enforce and apply a style, it's really not hard to adopt a style.

And **when a team can't even settle on something as simple as naming and whitespace, how are they supposed to even agree on what a good design and code organisation should be?!** Teams need to find agreement on the easy things and have constructive conflicts on the ones that are hard.

[image]

Maybe a tool could **render** the code the way you want, but leave all the underlying stuff in tact. Good luck understanding your stacktraces, debug windows and other tools that will take the binary form. Or do you propose generating PDBs that match your style too?!

Comment: Completely agree. One other thing (unless this was achieved via "rendering" magic) is that when you commit/check-in the changes the version control system would show that you had created a whole load of changes to multiple files, even if you have only actually fixed a single character. This would make it very hard to see what the *actual* change was.